# Simulating strike force graph on an LED strip

Tags: python, math, visualization, physics, led

I have an LED strip that will be mounted to my leg.  I would like to create visually the effect of that force that is transmitted to my foot as it hits the ground.  In other words, I would like to have the bottom of the LED strip start to light up as my foot strikes the ground, then get brightest as the force is strongest, then fade out as my foot lifts up again.  I would also like this to be displayed in the number of LEDs that light up up the leg (ie. when the force is strongest, the most number of LEDs will be lit, and the brightness will fall off from bottom to top).  I would like to do this in python, and the API for the library I am using requires an array of brightness values (0 to 1).

Comment: What is your question? Do you you want advice on the hardware implementation side? This site tries to help with specific programming problems, so an example of the code you have so far would be useful.

Comment: There is actually no hardware involved for the question. I think what I am asking is how to create a 2D array that is the product of a normalized Gaussian function on the X axis and a normalized exponential function on the Y axis (using Python).

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce a graphic like this you'll need a series of measurements for the force, from some type of transducer I guess. Then you can convert the single force measurement into an exponential decay distribution easily using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
scale = np.arange(0,10)
amp = 100
lam = 1
value = 20 # Your measurement of force
intensity = value*amp*np.exp(-lam*scale)
```

If you want to create a sample input signal from Gaussian you can use scipy:

```
import scipy.stats
vrange = np.arange (-1,1,.1)
values = scipy.stats.distributions.norm.pdf(vrange* 2)*10
```

Then you can create a template exponential distribution and convolve them together to get a two-dimensional shape:

```
temp = amp*np.exp(-lam*scale)
intensity = np.outer(values, intensity)
```

Comment: There is actually no force sensor involved; I would like to figure out a mathematical approximation what that might look like in order to simulate it.